# How to use subnet-zero ip address in practice?

Tags: subnet, ipv4

I know that subnet-zero ip address refers to a subnet itself, while subnet-one ip address is used for broadcasting.

How can we use subnet-zero ip address?

Does any router have a capability to make use of subnet-zero ip address?

Answer (score 1):

For IPv4, [*RFC 943, Assigned Numbers*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc943) defined the use of the all-zeroes address:

> Special Addresses:
>
> In certain contexts, it is useful to have fixed addresses with
> functional significance rather than as identifiers of specific hosts.
> When such usage is called for, the address zero is to be interpreted
> as meaning "this", as in "this network". The address of all ones are
> to be interpreted as meaning "all", as in "all hosts". For example,
> the address 128.9.255.255 could be interpreted as meaning all hosts on
> the network 128.9.  Or, the address 0.0.0.37 could be interpreted as
> meaning host 37 on this network.

Routers use the all-zeros to refer to the network. You will find this in a routing table, where the network is expressed as the all-zeroes address. A loopback address (`/32`) is technically both the all-zeroes and the all-ones address for the network.

-BUT-

If your router supports it, you could use the all-zeroes and all-ones addresses by using a 31-bit mask on a point-to-point link. This has been a standard since the year 2000, although not everything supports it (in particular, Windows does not, but most enterprise-grade routers do). See [*RFC 3021, Using 31-Bit Prefixes on IPv4 Point-to-Point Links*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3021).

Also, IPv6 does not have broadcast, and you can use the all-zeroes and all-ones addresses.

Comment: Great! Thank you! Could you elaborate on "Routers use the all-zeros to refer to the network"?  For example, if i want to reject an incoming packet to subnet by checking the port number, does subnet-zero make sense?

Comment: You would use the network address (all-zeroes) and mask to restrict traffic for an entire network.